# Angular $anchorScroll yOffset not taking effect

Tags: angularjs, anchor-scroll

This is maybe a bit redundant but I have looked at a number of items on stackoverflow that deal with the YOffset in anchorScroll and I have copied the plunkers but my app is still not working. I have a number of controllers in my app (about 15 at this point) and it is set up like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [])

.run(['$anchorScroll', function($anchorScroll) {
  $anchorScroll.yOffset = 50;   
}])

...

.controller('blabla', function($scope, $http, $location, $anchorScroll) {
// this is the only controller that uses anchorScroll

  $scope.gotoPub = function(pub_nid) {
    var final_hash = 'n' + pub_nid;
    $location.hash(final_hash);
    $anchorScroll();
};
```

...

Now no matter what I set yOffset to in the 'run' method, could be 5000, 50, 10000 etc it has absolutely no effect on the actual scrolling... Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!!
- J

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was ?